# Any ideas how to replicate this inline dropdown menu using css/jquery

Tags: jquery, css, menu, drop-down-menu

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a plugin that exists to replicate an in-line dropdown/menu like this.  The key to note is that the spacing of the selected element should remain in sentance format.

[image]

when clicking the link, it should act as a drop-down menu..
[image]

I'd rather not write this from scratch if there is something out there similar.

NOTE: The dropdown value is selected and the href link text is replaced with the selected value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple little pop up on click for the specified element along with replacing the link text. I'm assuming you would want to store the selected sort type so I included a little sortKey variable as an example that you could use. Fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/GKwn3/2/

```
<div id="somecontent">Sort leads by <span id="sort" href="#">date created</span> displaying first name....</div>
<div id="pop">
    <div class="link" data-sort="first" >First Name</div>
    <div class="link" data-sort="last">Last Name</div>
    <div class="link" data-sort="company">Company</div>
    <div class="link" data-sort="rating">Rating</div>
    <div class="link" data-sort="created">Date Created</div>
    <div class="link" data-sort="updated">Date Updated</div>
</div>

var $menu = $('#pop');

$('#sort').click(function(e) {
    $menu.css({
        "left": e.offsetX + "px",
        "top": e.offSetY + "px"
    }).show();
});

$('#pop .link').click(function(e) {
    var ele = $(this);
    var sortKey = ele.attr('data-sort'); // save it somewhere
    $('#sort').html(ele.html().toLowerCase());

    $menu.hide();
});

#sort{
 color: blue;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;  
}

#pop{
 color: #444;   
 width: 95px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
}

.link:hover {
 color: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: exactly what I needed..I'll wrap that into a plugin.  Thanks @jesse

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/) offers what you're looking for. Check out their demos, specifically the one that works onclick. You could easily make your vision work with this plugin.

Comment: Not quite what i'm looking for.  I don't need hover functionality.  The user needs to be able to click on the href..and the dropdown will display and allow them to select a record.  The href value will then switch to the record selected.

Comment: @KevinJensen: You said you wanted a plugin that does it simply...I mean, you could easily add links that change the order the list or whatever sorts into this tooltip, couldn't you? hover functionality is just an added thing, but besides that this plugin does the trick. Or you could write it yourself--finding the mouse position and placing a div there is not so hard, or more specifically, below or next to an `a` tag which you want to do.

Comment: Yes I could hack this plugin up and get it to function as a drop-down menu like I need, but I'm looking to see if someone has already solved my use-case before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin and achieve what you want with some css changes

http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/clickmenu/demo/demo.html

and also this http://pop.seaofclouds.com/